WPF DataTrigger where value is NOT null
Enable the button DFSStart if textboxes DFSFolderName.Text DFSUsersM.Text have non-null values and comboboxes DFSSite DFSType have selecteditems.
it is also required to check DFSFoldername.Text: 1) show an error if the text length is <2 or >40, 2) show an error if the folder exists at the specified path.
`<Grid>
                    <TabControl Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <TabItem Header="DFS">
                            <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="50">
                                    </RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="50">
                                    </RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="50">
                                    </RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="50">
                                    </RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="150">
                                    </RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="150">
                                    </RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="180">
                                    </RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="50">
                                    </RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="480"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Button x:Name="DFSStart" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="44" Grid.Row="7" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="144"/>
                                <Button x:Name="DFSExit" Grid.Column="2" Content="Exit" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="7" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="44" Width="144" />
                                <ComboBox x:Name="DFSSite" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="44" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="198" >
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="VLDK"/>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="VZHK"/>
                                </ComboBox>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="DFSType" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="44" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="198" >
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Projects"/>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Publics"/>
                                </ComboBox>
                                <TextBox x:Name="DFSFolderName" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="44" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="474" MaxLength="40"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="DFSUsersM" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="44" Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="474"/>
                                
                            </Grid>
    </TabItem></TabControl></Grid>`

